# Como saber la categoria de cada historia SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo una webapp para publicar historias.
Tengo la siguiente tabla en dond se almacenan las historias:

```
CREATE TABLE `historias` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `publico` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `anonimo` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `contenido` longtext NOT NULL,
  `fecha_creacion` date NOT NULL,
  `ult_mod` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `historias`
--

INSERT INTO `historias` (`id`, `id_usuario`, `publico`, `anonimo`, `titulo`, `contenido`, `fecha_creacion`, `ult_mod`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 101, '1', '0', 'El entierro', 'awfdaeljfhnwafbwbefjckbewjfbcwefnkewn', '2020-11-02', '2020-11-03 01:04:47', '1'),
(2, 1, '1', '1', 'El entierro', 'El entierro de la anaconda cavezona', '2020-11-03', '2020-11-03 00:43:17', '1'),
(3, 8, '1', '0', 'nibh. Phasellus', 'tellus id nunc interdum feugiat. Sed nec metus facilisis lorem tristique aliquet. Phasellus fermentum convallis ligula. Donec luctus', '2005-07-06', '2019-11-13 07:57:27', '1'),
(4, 51, '1', '1', 'malesuada id, erat.', 'ornare lectus justo eu arcu. Morbi sit amet massa. Quisque porttitor eros nec tellus.', '2008-05-02', '2020-11-15 16:53:10', '1'),
(5, 51, '1', '0', 'porttitor', 'commodo at, libero. Morbi accumsan laoreet ipsum.', '2005-06-12', '2021-06-02 04:16:08', '1'),
(6, 93, '1', '1', 'consectetuer adipiscing elit.', 'nec, diam. Duis mi enim, condimentum eget, volutpat ornare, facilisis eget, ipsum. Donec sollicitudin adipiscing ligula. Aenean gravida nunc sed', '2013-06-05', '2021-07-25 14:57:32', '1'),
(7, 47, '1', '1', 'nunc id', 'a purus.', '1998-08-02', '2020-01-25 21:37:14', '1'),
(8, 27, '1', '1', 'fermentum', 'elementum at, egestas a, scelerisque sed, sapien. Nunc pulvinar arcu et pede. Nunc sed orci lobortis', '2011-02-01', '2019-11-20 02:12:05', '1'),
(9, 25, '1', '1', 'dolor. Fusce feugiat.', 'Mauris ut', '2011-10-20', '2020-05-10 08:19:03', '1'),
(10, 31, '1', '1', 'auctor', 'pede. Nunc sed orci lobortis augue scelerisque mollis. Phasellus libero mauris, aliquam', '2000-04-19', '2020-04-07 20:38:45', '1');
```

Como una historia puede pertencer a una o varias categorias, hice una tabla extra para almacenar las categorias:

```
CREATE TABLE `categorias` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `nombre` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `status` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `categorias`
--

INSERT INTO `categorias` (`id`, `nombre`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 'ACCION', 1),
(2, 'REFLEXION', 1),
(3, 'TRAICION', 1),
(4, 'VENGANZA', 1),
(5, 'COMICA', 1),
(6, 'DRAMATICO', 1),
(7, 'AVENTURA', 1),
(8, 'AMOR', 1);
```

Y una tabla para asignarselas a cada historia:

```
CREATE TABLE `h_categorias` (
  `id_historia` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_categoria` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `h_categorias`
--

INSERT INTO `h_categorias` (`id_historia`, `id_categoria`) VALUES
(2, 1),
(2, 2),
(2, 3),
(2, 4),
(2, 5),
(2, 6),
(2, 7),
(2, 8),
(1, 2),
(1, 5),
(1, 6),
(1, 8),
(1, 1);
```

Ahora para el sistema de despliegue de todas las historias en la pantalla principal de la webapp quiero hacer una consulta que devuelva: TITULO, CONTENIDO, FECHA DE CREACION y enliste los nombres de las categorias checkeandolos con 1 si la tienen o con 0 si no.
Algo como esto:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|TITULO   | CONTENIDO | FECHA CREACION | ACCION | REFLEXION | TRAICION | VENGANZA |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Historia|Lorem itsum|  02/09/1998    |    0   |      1    |    1     |     0    |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Hasta ahora llevo esto:

```
SELECT titulo, contenido, fecha_creacion, COUNT(h_categorias.id_categoria) 
FROM historias  
INNER JOIN h_categorias on historias.id_historia = h_categorias.id_historia 
INNER JOIN categorias on h_categorias.id_categoria = categorias.nombre 
WHERE historias.status=1 and usuarios.status =1 and historias.publico = 1
```

Pero creo que no estoy ni cerca :(

Comment: Esto es un ejercicio o es algo real? porque si es real, eso lo deberia solucionar quien muestre los datos, no tu query...

Comment: Es un ejercicio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que buscas es algo que de una u otra forma, es muy consultado en el sitio, [transformar filas en columnas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D%20filas%20a%20columnas). La idea es mala, por que es una transformación que debiera estar del lado de la vista y no de los datos. La única forma, menos mala, es cuando defines un número estricto de columnas a mostrar, en tu caso quieres una matriz con las 8 categorías posibles.

```
SELECT h.id,
       h.titulo, 
       h.fecha_creacion, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN hc.id_categoria = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'ACCION',
       MAX(CASE WHEN hc.id_categoria = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'REFLEXION',
       MAX(CASE WHEN hc.id_categoria = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'TRAICION',
       MAX(CASE WHEN hc.id_categoria = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'VENGANZA',
       MAX(CASE WHEN hc.id_categoria = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'COMICA',
       MAX(CASE WHEN hc.id_categoria = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'DRAMATICO',
       MAX(CASE WHEN hc.id_categoria = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'AVENTURA',
       MAX(CASE WHEN hc.id_categoria = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'AMOR'
       FROM historias h
       LEFT JOIN h_categorias hc 
             on h.id = hc.id_historia
       WHERE h.status=1
             and h.publico = "1"
       GROUP BY
             h.id,
             h.titulo, 
             h.fecha_creacion;
```

El funcionamiento es mediante una agrupación y una dunción de agregación condicional mediante `CASE WHEN hc.id_categoria = <nro categoria> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` para cada una de las categorías de interés.

¿Y sí hay más categorías? seguramente es la pregunta que sigue. Y aquí sí, la solución más mala: adaptar la consulta anterior a una consulta dinámica para generar la sentencia que contemple todas las categorías.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN hc.id_categoria = ', c.id, ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ', c.nombre)
      ) INTO @sql
FROM
  categorias c;
  
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT h.id, h.titulo, h.fecha_creacion, ', @sql, ' 
     
       FROM historias h
       LEFT JOIN h_categorias hc 
             on h.id = hc.id_historia
       LEFT JOIN categorias c 
             on c.id = hc.id_categoria
       WHERE h.status=1
             and h.publico = "1"
       GROUP BY
             h.id,
             h.titulo, 
             h.fecha_creacion;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Decir que esto es malo, es poco riguroso, digamos que:

1. Es algo que, ya dijimos, debiera manejarse de lado de la vista
2. Es muy poco lógico que una consulta no sea determinista en el número de columnas
3. las consultas dinámicas por lo general no aprovechan las optimizaciones que pueda hacer el motor.
4. La lógica es mucho más compleja de mantener y modificar

[Ver fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=21f6f3b281fa6d938d2845e0cbda9141)